# Cassandra triggers: run on all nodes in the cluster, or only node receiving the original request?

Tags: cassandra

I'm looking into using triggers in a Cassandra cluster: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html

I know triggers execute before the actual DML statement, so they can modify/augment incoming data, but what I can't seem to find an answer to is: Will the trigger fire only once, on the node receiving the original request, or will it fire on each node in a cluster as the data is replicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you haven't find answer yet, Trigger will fire once only, on the node receiving the original request.